# How can I display 'word count' in Calibre while browsing my Library?

Tags: calibre, metadata

I use [Calibre](http://www.calibre-ebook.com/), to manage my library of eBooks.  It is easy to include the size of the book, but with images and such that can be misleading.   I notice on [Smashwords](http://www.smashwords.com/) they often include a word count in the books in the description.  Is the word count an attribute that Calibre can display?  If so how?

Comment: Can we make a feature request? I'd like to see word count too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not straightforward but there is a Calibre extension that you can install : [**Count Pages**](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=134000#post1547631) (it counts pages but it also counts words). It works **only for MOBI and EPUB** files so it won't be able to show the word count of books you have only in Amazon Kindle format for instance.

First you need to **install Count Pages** :

- In Calibre Preferences window, go to *Extensions*, then click on *Get new extension modules*
- Look for *Count Pages* and install it

You also have to **create a custom column** :

- In the Preferences window, click on *Add a custom column* and then on the + button
- Name the column "Words" for instance (the first field is used for advanced search and does not allow capitals so you can enter "words")
- Select *Integer* as the column type
- Create the column and apply changes
- Check that the column now shows up in your library (but it is empty and you need to populate it)

Finally, **use Count Pages to populate your new column** :

- You should have a new *Count pages* button in the main menu : Select *Customize the extension module* in the drop-down list
- In the *Word count options* select your custom column
- You don't need to bother with the other options but you could create a "page" count column too if you'd like
- Select all the books you need counted and click on the *Count pages* main menu button
- You might get an error message saying that it could not process x books because it did not find them in a supported format
- It takes a while because the plugin needs to open and process each file
- Your column finally gets updated.

Each time you add a new book in the library you will need to use that *Count Pages* button to fill in the column for this book.

Calibre will need to be restarted several times in the process. My Calibre is in French so the words I used in my answer might not exactly be the ones used in the English interface, sorry.

Comment: Your words are close enough that I could figure it out.  Thanks :)

Comment: Boy this could be simpler! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where's the main menu in calibre? I don't appear to have one.

Comment: I was talking about the big icon bar at the top of Calibre window.

Comment: Thank you! This was killing me.

Comment: I don't have the Count Pages button on the main menu! Help!

Comment: @Cathal did you install the extension? Maybe the menu bar is too wide for the screen and you need to click the double arrow at the right?